# What is the use of asterisk (*) type in Flow and what is the equivalent of that in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

First of all, I am mostly familiar with TypeScript. Flow looks very similar to TS in many ways, but I recently stumbled upon an asterisk (*) type. At first, I thought it was a synonym for "any", but now, after reading some of the release notes for Flow, I see that it's not. I skimmed through all the official docs and was not able to find any usage of "*".

So, what is it and when to use it? But also, what would be a direct equivalent of that in TypeScript?

Comment: can you show some example code demonstrating it's use?  It **sounds like** a [Literal Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/), meaning that the value of that particular variable could only be `*`.  In Typescript, you can create String Literal Types. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Plenty of examples can be seen in flow definition for the Kefir.js library: https://github.com/rpominov/kefir/blob/master/kefir.js.flow. For instance, check the never() method. It has the signature Observable<*>. I really don't get this one, as never() doesn't return anything, so I would assume it would have a signature of Observable<void>. On the other hand, it could mean it has a side effect, so void is not good either.

Comment: But also, from the official Flow changelog: "We now treat missing type parameters as any. For example, previously ReactElement was treated as ReactElement<*, *, *>. Now it's treated as ReactElement<any, any, any>". Before reading this one, I assumed that any and \* were the same...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edit: Since I originally wrote this answer, I have learned that `*` is unsafe when it appears at module boundaries. I can't recommend using it, and it may be removed in the future.

It just tells Flow to infer a type parameter, rather than making you write it out explicitly:

```
function foo(): Array<*> {
  return [5];
}

// Flow issues an error:
//    2:   return [5];
//                 ^ number. This type is incompatible with
//    10: (foo(): Array<string>);
//                     ^ string
(foo(): Array<string>);
```

([try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAXIgggJ3wEMBPAHgCoA+RAbwChFF8BTKEfJAbQFYBdANz0AvvXoB6cYgBiAGzgB3RDADOKkCxWIiSFoTj4sEqU0QAmHE1btOiXoOOmnz5wD1EYEAFsARnoB0iAAqABaqiFAkAA4sylowkHBeUUSwPrKxCjBQIY6mAIwADDhoKOjYeISkZCpQ+AkA5lQYQpIu7R3utfVgDfSlqJg4BMTk3Y3NQkA))

It is different from `any` -- `any` is an unsafe type, so if you replaced `*` with `any` in this example, Flow would not give you any errors. You could replace it with `number` and Flow would give you a similar error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It is clear to me the use case for that in Flow now. But could you also help out with the second part of my question? What would be the similar syntax for TS, if any?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, as I'm not familiar with Typescript. The site works best if you ask only one question per question, so maybe the second part would be a good candidate for a separate question?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a good advice, so I'll follow it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk `*` in Flow tells it to infer the type, which was already answered by [Nat Mote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901387/nat-mote)

Additionally Typescript has no direct equivalent for the asterisk, and consequently it's unable to be told to infer a type. It does however, like Flow, infer types automatically in some specific cases. [TypeScript Type Inference Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html), [Type Inference Examples](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-inference.html)

Check out `unique features` on this page:
[Differences between Flow and TypeScript](https://github.com/niieani/typescript-vs-flowtype)