# What do the angle brackets and asterisk mean in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What do the angle brackets and asterisk mean in this expression?

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component<*> {
  render() {
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) type argument. It specifies that Flow should *infer* the type of the first type argument, in other words infer the shape of props, see [this answer on `<*>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106189/what-is-the-use-of-asterisk-type-in-flow-and-what-is-the-equivalent-of-that). This essentially let's you specify an object of any shape for Flow to infer its type. Say you have two props, `foo` and `bar`. You could do this:

```
type Props = {
  foo: number,
  bar: string
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> { … }
```

Or, if you don't want proptyping, you can just do:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<*> { … }
```

And access the props all the same. Flow just infers it's an object with `foo` and `bar`.