# Type 'State' does not satisfy the constraint '(state: any, ...args: any[]) => any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

It is probably a noobish question, but how do I deal with the Typescript error TS2344?

> Type 'State' does not satisfy the constraint '(state: any, ...args: any[]) => any'.

Here is the code fragement of my `sagas.ts` where the error occurs

```js
function* loadPageFull(action: Actions.LoadPageFullAction ) {
    if (!action.id)
        return;
    const currentPageFull: Interfaces.PageFull = 
      yield (select<Top.State>(Selectors.getPageFull(action.id))); // <-- error occurs here

    if (!currentPageFull || action.forceReload) {
        // here we query the API of the backend and return some JSON
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be the `Top.State` in the line with the `yield`. The curious  thing is that I did not have the error before updating Typescript to version 3.6.4.

**EDIT:** The `getPageFull` is defined in `selectors.ts` as

```js
const getPageFullInner = (state: State, id: number) => state.pagesFull.get(id);
export const getPageFull = (id: number) => (state: Top.State) 
    => getPageFullInner(foobar(state), id);
```

The `foobar()` function is also defined there

```
export const foobar = (state: State) => state.foobar;
```

#### References

- [How to go about understanding the type ...args: any[]) => any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726326/how-to-go-about-understanding-the-type-args-any-any)
- https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#selectselector-args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `select` is:

```
export function select<Fn extends (state: any, ...args: any[]) => any>(
  selector: Fn,
  ...args: Tail<Parameters<Fn>>
): SelectEffect
```

So the first generic parameter has to be a function type (specifically `(state: any, ...args: any[]) => any`), but you're giving it `State`.

You don't need to specify the generic parameter, as it can be inferred from the argument, so you can simply write:

```
select(Selectors.getPageFull(action.id))
```

Comment: I just now found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632123/what-do-the-angle-brackets-and-asterisk-mean-in-react which helped me to understand. How is this prototyping with angle brackets called? Do you have a link to an official documentation on that?

Comment: The angle brackets are used for generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html